# docker-compose on mac (el capitan) extremely slow

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I just erased the docker for mac program because it was very bloated, and I installed with brew docker and docker-compose. I followed [this](https://pilsniak.com/how-to-install-docker-on-mac-os-using-brew/) blog post.

docker works fine, but docker-compose is extremely slow.
I know that there is a fix of setting localunixsocket.local in the /etc/hosts file, but that doesnt work for me. I tried every combination, but nothing works.

These are the versions I'm using on el capitan:

**docker**
Docker version 17.11.0-ce, build 1caf76c

**docker-compose**
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Try to put these aliases in your `/env/hosts` file, so your 127.0.0.1 line looks like this:

`127.0.0.1 localhost localunixsocket localunixsocket.local localunixsocket.lan localunixsocket.localdomain`

Comment: tnx for the answer, but I was and idiot and left running a process that was heavy on memory, terminating it solved the problem...there was nothing wrong with docker-compose or docker...